# Where to hire graphic designers for mobile games?

Tags: graphics, graphics-design

I need to find someone talented to create a series of 2D graphics a la cart for my mobile games.  My graphics are just not impressive enough, but the game play is solid and fun.

This is sort of a multi-part question:

Where do I start to find someone?

What should I expect to pay for custom sprites and backgrounds?

What kinds of terms should I use so I receive exclusive, royalty-free, ownership of the artwork when it's finished?

Comment: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Aside from Diadistis' redirection, you might like to get in touch with a skilled pixel artist at [DeviantArt](http://www.deviantart.com/)

Comment: @Axidos: It's dangerous to suggest that; DA's pixel gallery is flooded with poor quality work, because many people misunderstand the medium and techniques.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: Hence why I said _skilled_; he'll need to dig deep and search. Great pixel artists do exist there, they're just buried under gallons of [CENSORED]. I'm glad the answers have provided alternate sites! I wasn't sure if there were any.

Comment: Hi try to contact with prem rajah : look at his webside and you can find his work. He is good.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of websites around that have places for posting career and freelance opportunities. The most awesome places I know of for Pixel Art are [Way of the Pixel](http://www.wayofthepixel.net/) and the Spriter's Resource. For any other art, I'd check out Conceptart.org or DeviantArt to find other artists.

This amount will vary based on what you negotiate with your artist and what you are looking for, I couldn't reasonably give you any sort of potential figure without knowing what you are going for. And even then, its highly subject to all kinds of other things.

You need to negotiate a transfer of rights between the artist and yourself. In general, getting a professional artist to sign over rights raises the cost but its necessary to get said rights to reproduce the work. (You could face some serious consequences if you do not)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Pixelation, mentioned above, there's [PixelJoint](http://www.pixeljoint.com/), home to numerous professional pixel and low-spec artists for hire. You can post job listings in the [forum](http://www.pixeljoint.com/forum/), and you should be able to discuss and negotiate pay on an individual basis. You can get an idea of the skills of various artists by browsing the gallery.

As for pricing, individual sprites and basic animations will tend to run you $50–$100 apiece, while backgrounds are typically more costly. It really depends on the style you want to go for, but I think high-quality low-spec art is generally more time-consuming (since it is so detail-oriented) and hence costlier than other forms of game art.

Edit: [Here's](http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/AdamSaltsman/20090724/2571/Pixel_Art_Freelance_Best_Practices__Guidelines.php) a great article all about the business side of pixel art: when and where to use it, what to expect from it, and how much it costs. All of the art in the article is by [Fool](http://www.pixeljoint.com/p/6741.htm), one of the most (if not the very most) highly skilled and respected pixel artists around.

Answer (score 2):

One place that is always worth posting is something like the [Gamedev Help Wanted](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/forum.asp?forum_id=8) forum. It gets a large amount of interest from artists and programmers.

As for terms (basing this off mostly common-sense), you would want to purchase the ownership rather than license the art. Just make sure you nail that point with your artist.